# Display all the images in thumbnail view from a database table(SQL Server) in VB 2010

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

We are doing a project using VB2010 as front end SQL server 2008R2 as backend.We need the code to display all the images in thumbnail view in VB when we open a database table.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `thumbnail` using [Image.GetThumbnailImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.getthumbnailimage.aspx) Method.